# How to show $(X,d)$ is not totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,y)=\min(1, |x-y|)$

I am trying to prove that this metric space is not totally bounded. It is obvious from $d(x,y)$ that $d(x,y)\leq 1$, so I am confused as to how this metric space is not totally bounded. Couldn't you just take any $e>0$ and union together a collection of open balls until the union has a radius of greater than $1$? Sorry if I explained this in a confusing way, I am just not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Can you cover the space with balls of size $\frac{1}{8}$?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is what is confusing me. Since d(x,y) =< 1, if I picked balls that had a size of 1/8, couldn't I just keep unioning them together until it covers the whole space, which would then give me a finite union of balls?

Comment: Sure, you can keep unioning, but why is the union finite?  You need to keep using more and more balls of size $\frac{1}{8}$.  When you union them, you must count the number of balls of size $\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider balls of size at most $\frac{1}{8}$.  Then the points in $\mathbb{Z}$ must be in distinct balls (since the distance between two integers is exactly $1$ by the minimum).  Therefore, you need infinitely many balls to cover $\mathbb{Z}$, let alone $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the fact that the metric $d$ is bounded (by 1) with the harder fact that $(X,d)$ is totally bounded, which means that for any $r>0$ we can cover $X$ with finitely many balls of radius $r$. So a totally bounded space has a bounded metric , and this example is to show the reverse does not hold. If it doesn't hold for a metric space, then it also does not holds for a truncated version of the metric; if the balls get  small enough, we'll need infinitely many of them to cover the space.

Comment: So R is not totally bounded no matter what metric is on it? I know that it is obvious that you cannot cover R with a finite number of balls when it has the standard metric, but I thought that this could change depending on what metric it was equipped with.

Comment: @VG3 not with the "trunctated" metric like here. If a space $(X,d)$ is not totally bounded ,there is some $r>0$ such that it cannot be covered by finitely many $r$-balls, but this implies that it cannot be covered by finitely many $s$-balls either for *all* $s \le r$. So even if we truncate $d$ by $r$, so we'd define $d'(x,y) = \min(d(x,y), r)$, the $\frac{r}{2}$ balls come back to bite you. You could give the reals a totally different metric (consider it as a subspace of $S^1$ and inherit that metric) and then it could be totally bounded.